# Text wont style itself bold

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to create an **A** element link using variables and when I try to bold the text. it just comes back as `<b>App: </b>` instead of **App:**

Code:

```
//Set Webpage App Title
function setAppTitle() {
    const header = document.getElementById('header');
    const a = document.createElement('a');
    const appText = 'App: '.bold()
    const text = document.createTextNode(appText + appName);
    a.setAttribute('href', "http://example.com/applicaton?id=");
    a.setAttribute('id', "appTitle");
    a.appendChild(text);
    header.appendChild(a);
}
```

Comment: `<b>` in a text node is `<b>` - why not create a `b` element inside the `a` element, and put the text inside that - or ...  `a.style.fontWeight = 'bold'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[.bold() has been deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/bold) and you should not use it. Also take time to determine if you should use a [`<strong>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/strong) or [`<b>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/b) element. However, if you're trying to inject HTML into an element, use `.innerHTML` like so:

```
//Set Webpage App Title
function setAppTitle() {
    const header = document.getElementById('header');
    const a = document.createElement('a');
    const appText = '<strong>App:</strong> ';
    a.setAttribute('href', "http://example.com/applicaton?id=");
    a.setAttribute('id', "appTitle");
    a.innerHTML = appText;
    header.appendChild(a);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `.bold` method of string is deprecated and only surrounds the string with `<b>` and `</b>`. See
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/bold

If you want to construct the html manually in your function, simply create a `b` element yourself:

```
//Set Webpage App Title
function setAppTitle() {
    const header = document.getElementById('header');
    const a = document.createElement('a');
    const b = document.createElement('b');
    const appText = 'App: '
    const text = document.createTextNode(appText + appName);
    a.setAttribute('href', "http://example.com/applicaton?id=");
    a.setAttribute('id', "appTitle");
    a.appendChild(text);
    b.appendChild(a)
    header.appendChild(b);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are adding HTML `<b>` into textnode.

The simplest solution is to add it via innerHTML:

```
a.innerHTML = "<b>" + appText + appName + "</b>";
```